# How to store words from a text file into an array?

Tags: arrays, c, dictionary

I'm trying to read a text file called "olaola.dict", some sort of a dictionary, that currently holds 10 words each with 5 letters and store the words into an array of strings. I'm using a char** pointer that points to an array of pointers in which each pointer points to a word from the dictionary.

So far, I've developed this code. It is printing the last 7 words correctly, but not the first three. The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW 10  /* 10 words */
#define COL 6  /* 5 letters in each word + Null terminator*/

int main(void) {
  int i, j;
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  char **ptr = NULL;

  ptr = (char**)malloc(ROW * sizeof(char*));
  fp = fopen("olaola.dict","r");
  for (i=0 ; i < 15; i++) {
    if ((ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * COL)) == NULL) {
      printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
          return -1;
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%s", ptr[i]);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < ROW; i++){
    printf("Word %d:%s\n", i+1,ptr[i]);
  }

  for (i=0 ; i < ROW; i++)
    free(ptr[i]);
  free(ptr);
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
/*
   ptr[]                0   1   2   3   4   5   6   
    +--------+        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |      --|------->| w | o | r | d | 0 | 0 |\0 |
    +--------+        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |      --|------->| w | o | r | d | 0 | 1 |\0 |
    +--------+        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |      --|------->| w | o | r | d | 0 | 2 |\0 |
    +--------+        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |      --|------->| w | o | r | d | 0 | 3 |\0 |
    +--------+        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |      --|------->| w | o | r | d | 0 | 4 |\0 |
    +--------+        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+


*/
```

The output is:

```
Word 1:[p:�
Word 2:0[p:�
Word 3:P[p:�
Word 4:Carlo
Word 5:Andre
Word 6:MESSI
Word 7:Arroz
Word 8:Doces
Word 9:Carro
Word 10:Tevez
```

Here is also the text file olaola.dict

```
lista
         
    Sabes    ontem     Carlo
Andre

MESSI

Arroz         Doces             Carro            Tevez
```

As you can see, there is no specific position for the words to be.
What would be the correct way to solve this problem?
(In another note, would it be wiser and more efficient to use a 2D array, even though the dictionary can have like 5k words ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the first for loop goes from zero to 14 instead of from zero to 9. This means that the code writes beyond the boundaries of the array. I assume that this writes to the memory being allocated for the first 3 words and this is the reason why you see the wrong values for these words. Correct the for loop and see if this solves the issue.

Comment: That solved it right there. Thank you for answering. Do you think this is a good way to store words in an array from a dictionary text file, considering it can have up to 5k words ? Or an 2D array would be more efficient (memory wise).

Comment: If the words are all 5 characters long, a 2D array would be more efficient in terms of memory, since you do not need the pointers to the words.  Additionally storing the data in a 2D array would result in a better runtime performance due to a better locality of the data resulting in a better cache performance

Answer (score 0):

you problem is in this line

```
for (i=0 ; i < 15; i++) {
```

it's supposed to be:

```
for (i=0 ; i < ROW; i++)
```

because you should allocate till `ptr[9]`, but you are allocating till `ptr[14]` which will produce undefined behavior as the size of the **array = 10**